# Intersection of planes in a four dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $V$ a four dimensional vector space. Let $v_1,v_2,v_3$ be three linearly independent vectors and the lines they span $L_1,L_2,L_3$ respectively. Let $W\subset V$ a two dimensional subspace.

> Can $L_1\oplus L_2$, $L_1\oplus L_3$ and $L_2\oplus L_3$ all have a one dimensional intersection with W?

This obviously cannot happen in $3$ dimensions just by thinking of the $L_i$ as the coordinate planes. But four dimensions are kinda hard to visualize.

Feel free to assume that the ground field has characteristic $0$.

Comment: Try writing down the sort of basis $W$ would need to have, in terms of $v_1, v_2, v_3$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Oh I think I see. assuming that the $v_i$ are $e_1,e_2,e_3$, we can say the intersections $L_i\cap W$ are spanned by $(a,b,0,0),(0,c,d,0),(e,0,f,0)$ respectively. And these are linearly independant so they span a $3$-dim space contradicting that $W$ is two dimensions? Do we not need to worry about the $a,b,c,d,e,f$ possibly being zero?

Comment: You've pretty much got it. Concerning your last question, note that the question says that the intersections all have dimension exactly 1.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that there will be some additional work to be done, because it's possible for at least some of the values $a,b,...$ to be zero.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong It can actually happen. Please see the example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is possible. Let $L_1,L_2,L_3$ be the spans of $e_1,e_2,e_3$ respectively.Let $W=\text{Span}(e_1+e_2,e_3)$.Then you can see that

- $(L_1\oplus L_2) \cap W=\text{Span}(e_1+e_2)$
- $(L_1\oplus L_3) \cap W=\text{Span}(e_3)$
- $(L_2\oplus L_3) \cap W=\text{Span}(e_3)$

So they are all one dimensional as desired.